# Two Columns on the same axis in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following requirement. I have a table with 4 columns. `ncpus`, `ndisks`, `f1`, `f2`. I need a scatter plot that shows the behavior of `f1` and `f2` with change in `ncpus` and `ndisks`; i.e. consider the following data:

```
ncpus |  ndisks |    f1 |    f2
------+---------+-------+-------
   10 |     255 |  6.63 |  7.37
   50 |    1024 | 26.89 | 30.56
  100 |    1024 | 28.69 | 36.03
```

and so on. Now what i need is a scatter plot that plots `ncpus`, `ndisks` on Y-axis and `f1`, `f2` on X-axis. Can anyone show me how this is done in excel?

Comment: Non-programming. Please ask this at Super User

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it's not really possible and you should consider surface plot or several plots. Anyway, you can have primary and secondary axes in scatter plot, but you **can only plot series on one axis**. Of course you could plot f1 and f2 on ncpus axis and then plot a bogus series on f2. The process of adding secondary y axis is described by [MS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-HP001234165.aspx)